# Код работает! Вопрос, можно его улучшить, доработать? Может что то упущено?

Tags: php, sql

```
function FormulaPaginatorRCAT($cid,$page = 0){// Входящие данные: id раздела и страница.
$url = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rid WHERE razdel='.$cid.' AND v_2=0';
$count_rid = mysqli_fetch_assoc(sql($url));
$count_rid = $count_rid['COUNT(*)'];
$limit = 15;// 15 сообщений
$count_page = ceil($count_rid/$limit);
if($page > $count_page){$page = $count_page;}
if($page <= 0){$offset = 0;}else{$offset = (($limit * $page) - $limit);}
return array('limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset, 'count_page' => $count_page); }
```

после получения данных делаем запрос

```
$paginator = FormulaPaginatorRCAT($cid,$p);
'SELECT перечисляем FROM еще перечисляем WHERE условия LIMIT '.$paginator['limit'].' OFFSET '.$paginator['offset'];
```

Comment: напрочь упущено форматирование кода и подстановка параметров в запросы в нормальном виде

Comment: Можно пример? ссылку.

Comment: _Никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса, _всегда_ используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Обычно я уверен что параметры не будут исковерканы перед тем как вставить их напрямую в запрос.
mysqli_stmt_bind_param - Очень много новых функций, ради подстановки. Да и в самом отвратительном справочнике.

Comment: ну да, те кто 10 лет программируют, почему то считают что биндинг параметров и проверка результатов функций это правильно и надо использовать, а те кто только начал изучать пхп сразу уверен что параметры и результаты всегда корректны и форматирование для слабаков.

Comment: (int)$var = $_GET['num']; // это форматирование не достаточно?
'запрос'.$var;

Answer (score -1):

```
    function FormulaPaginatorRCAT($cid,$page = 0){// Входящие данные: id раздела и страница.
    $url = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rid WHERE razdel=' . $cid . ' AND v_2=0';
    $count_rid = mysqli_fetch_assoc(sql($url));
    $count_rid = $count_rid['COUNT(*)'];
    $limit = 15;      // 15 сообщений
    $count_page = ceil($count_rid / $limit);
    if($page > $count_page){
          $page = $count_page;
    }
    if($page <= 0){
          $offset = 0;
    } else {
          $offset = (($limit * $page) - $limit);
    }
    return array(
              'limit' => $limit,
              'offset' => $offset,
              'count_page' => $count_page
           );
 }
```

Comment: _Никогда_ не рекомендуйте код с переменными, подставляемыми в текст запроса и без того 80% сайтов уязвимо к sql-инъекциям и подобными советами вы лишь увеличиваете из количество. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: не делаю форматирование кода из-за того что я его прессую для себя.